# Allow reducing stock while WooCommerce order in pending status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, stock

In case the customer pays online (using for example PayPal) the WooCommerce creates order and then wait for the payment. This "waiting" is order status `pending`. No stock is being reduced during this period which is very bad. The stock is reduced after the succesfull payment by changing the order status to `on-hold`. But sometimes the payment can take up 30minutes and during these 30minutes the order keeps in `pending` status and the stock is not reduced, therefore if its a last piece of a product on stock, it is still available during this period. Therefore if I have only 1-3 pieces of each product on stock, there is a big possibility, that if I will have only one last piece of a product on stock, someone else will come and buy it during these 30 minutes, which leads to situation, where the last piece can be sold twice, which is inacceptible. Therefore I need to reduce the stock immediately after creating any order with any type of payment and any type of shipping. Therefore I tried to create a snippet, which will use a hook `woocommerce_order_status_changed` and it should reduce the stock always when the order status changed to `pending`, because `pending` status does not reduces the stock. I do not know if this is the right attitude how to solve it. Could anyone help pls? I tried these two snippets, but without any changes of behaviour:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'pending' )) {
        $reduce_stock = true;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_stock_reduction_based_on_status', 20, 4 );
function order_stock_reduction_based_on_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( $new_status == 'pending'){
    $stock_reduced = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', true );
        if( empty($stock_reduced) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'barion' ){
            wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the following code line to allow stock to be reduced on pending order status *(WooCommerce will do the job triggering [the function `wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.1/includes/wc-stock-functions.php#L79-L108) on pending orders*):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but I already found this code before and it is not working at all. It does not matter if I will choose PayPal or another payment service, as soon as the order is switched to ```pending```, no reduction of stock. If I force to switch it to ```on-hold```, it switches immediately but still no reduction. Is there any way how to force reduction of the stock programaticaly manually?

Comment: @MiroslavHrnčíř I will check that for tomorrow on last WooCommerce version and I will try find the correct way to do it.

Comment: If  I switch it manually in the administration to ```on-hold```, it switches and reduces the stock correctly.  I even tried ```$order->update_status( 'on-hold' );```, ```wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);```, etc Still the same - no reduction.

Comment: You need to also remove the opposite action wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels on the hook - check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is the only working solution I found now:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'force_new_order_status', 20, 1 );
function force_new_order_status( $order )
{ 
if( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') ) 
        $order->set_status( 'on-hold', 'Forced status by a custom script (this note is not neccessary and can be deleted)' ); 
}
```

There is only one problem: in case of failed payment the stock is not getting back. Therefore there must be another action made like automatic cancelling of non-paid orders after (for example) 60mins, or use specific hook(s) from the payment gateway.
Anyway what I have learned today, that there is a massive difference between `set_status` and `update_status`. Beginners like me, beware! :-)
So this way I switch every new order made by WooCommerce automatically in `pending` state (which is not reducing the ordered stock) to `on-hold` state (which does reducing the ordered stock) which is working solution to my problem. Maybe too easy for advanced programmers but because I did not find correct working solution of my question for two days of searching, I am posting it even it is so trivial to save another beginner's time, because as I found during searching: I am not the only one who needs to reduce the stock immediately when the order is made. So this is the way! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add stock reducing hook (as LoicTheAztec already answered), but you need to also remove the opposite wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels hook too. To remove it correctly, you need to run it when it is already hooked, so you need to wrap it into init hook.

**Following works for me (Woocommerce 5.4.1) - ensure the Pending status reduce stock levels:**

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels');
    remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels');
});
```